# Memory error only in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory, spyder

doing the following causes a MemoryError in my Spyder Python IDE:

```
>>> from numpy  import *
>>> a_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+4
>>> b_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>    
MemoryError
>>>
```

THis is weird, since the memory usage in the statusbar of Spyder shows that only approx. 25% of my memory is used. Furthermore, when generating even a higher number of these large 7000*7000 arrays in the standard Python IDE GUI, everything works fine.

```
>>> from numpy  import *
>>> a_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+4
>>> b_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+1
>>> c_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+1
>>> d_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+1
>>> e_flt = ones((7000,7000), dtype=float64)+1
```

Even with 5 floating point arrays created, memory requirements only amount to about a third of my total memory of 16GB. So this cannot be a real memory problem, then. I found a similiar question on this issue in a spyder google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spyderlib/qE9tiriT91s/0x3s2Aw-efMJ, however no answer was provided. It would really be nice if someone could help me with this paradoxical situation.
Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem on Debian Linux with Spyder 2.3.0.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) What's your Spyder version? and your platform (Windows, Linux, Mac)?

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba: My Spyder version is 2.2.5. and I am using Windows 7

Comment: Now I updated Spyder to version 2.3.1 using Python 2.7.6 32bits, Qt 4.8.4, PyQt4 (APIv2) 4.9.6 on Windows and the same Memory Error results even when trying to create the first array with 7000*7000 float elements (a_flt)! Something is completely wrong here!

Comment: 32 bits Python? You won't ever get to 16GB, you are limited by 4GB addressable memory.

Comment: @KingLui81 In your other thread you mentioned that you are using 32-bit Python because there isn't a 64-bit Python(x,y).  This is true but there are alternative science distributions like WinPython and Anaconda that have 64-bit versions.

Comment: It seems that the problem is the 32bit version. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032616/unexplainabe-memory-error-in-python). Although this really lets me wonder that in SPYDER I have left only about 500MB from the total 4GB limit.

Comment: There is a 64-bit version of Spyder at https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads. If Python(x,y) is just a bundle of packages, get the same packages as 64-bit versions.

Comment: I now installed 64-bit version of WinPython and everything works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Install 64bit version of [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and Spyder. This eliminated me this error.